# Is there any way to create a pair of template class containing each other?

Tags: c++

I wanna do sth like this:

A.hpp:

```
template <class B>
class A{
  B* B;
};
```

---

B.hpp:

```
template <class A>
class B{
  A* a;
};
```

and it always fails..

Comment: Can you give us a [mre] where it fails?

Comment: You have a circular dependency. You should also consider changing the template typenames so they don't conflict with the actual class names.

Comment: `A<B<A<B<A<B<..>>>>>>`

Comment: thanks bro,I was reading that topic @ HTNW

Comment: Ntice that `B` in `template <class B>
class A;` is unrelated to `class B` as between `int n = 42; void f(int n);`, So your code, as-is compile, `class A` and `B` are class with similar definition (only name of member change).

Answer (score 1):

You might use template template parameter (if appropriate):

```
template <template <typename> class C>
class A{
  C<A>* B;
};

template <template <typename> class C>
class B{
  C<B>* a;
};
```

So, `A<B>` and `B<A>` are both valid types.

Comment: thanks man,but that seems don't fit in my case